# Wordpress TinyMCE removes anchor tags if they wrap block elements when switching from text to visual

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I was able to disable this behavior in backend with this code:

```
function override_mce_options($initArray)
{
    $opts = '*[*]';
    $initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $initArray['valid_children'] = '+a[*]';
    return $initArray;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

It works if I paste this into the editor:

```
<a href="#" class="text-center text-info"><h5 class="title">Heading</h5></a>
```

and press update button without switching to visual mode. But when pasting and switching to visual mode the editor removes the anchor tag and leaves `h5` alone. I know some js is messing up with this but I have no idea what file is responsible for this and how to prevent this behavior.

Comment: First of all why are you trying to do that? The valid markup would be `<h5 class="title"><a href="#" class="text-center text-info">Heading</a></h5>`

Comment: According to HTML5 this markup is correct. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works perfectly. I just installed "Preserved HTML Editor Markup Plus" plugin and it solved all the issues I had with TinyMCE messing up with my html markup.